# Angularjs glyphicon query

Tags: angularjs

Hi guys i am working with Angularjs glyphicons here i want to show glyphicon star on html page
I am posting my code:-

```
<p>
  mycomponent works!
</p>
<span
 class=" glyphicon glyphicon-star"
></span>

so these my Component where i am using glyphicon-star but when do ng serve it is showing no icon on broswer

"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Above is my Bootstrap Version 3...I am not able to find what  step i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json has the dependency mentioned, but it is not used in your Angular application. To make it work please add the bootstrap css file in your **angular.json** file inside 
"architect" >> "build" >>
 "styles":[ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ]

Likewise add the bootstrap js file as:
"architect" >> "build" >>
"scripts": [ 
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
]

Bootstrap js file depends on jquery so first install jquery using command **npm install jquery@latest**.

Comment: It have not solve my problem it is giving me ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js error

Comment: The issue is get resolved by inserted <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" /> in index.html head section...thank you for your support